# neo4j-shell-tools, neo4j-shell auto-index and import command not found

Tags: shell, neo4j, centos, centos6

I'm trying to import data using the [Neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools) . But both the auto-index command and the import-csv/import-geoff commands are not found.

Google doesn't return much useful, and this seems too trivial to be true, but I really can't seem to find a solution.

I'm running Neo4j 2.0.0, using the Yum repository at [http://yum.neo4j.org/](http://yum.neo4j.org) (but with java 1.7.0_u45), on CentOS 6.5, latest tools-package from github.

I triple checked the location of the jars, they are located in `/usr/share/neo4j/lib` (but I also copied them to the `plugins` directory and root directory). 
There is also a `/var/lib/neo4j` directory, which holds my database. I cannot imagine I need to copy the jars to that "lib" directory...

Comment: Where did you put the jars? Are there any error messages in your logs? There is no Neo4j 1.9.8 !! Did you use the right version for your neo installation?

Comment: made an edit that shows a more clear directory structure... and the correct version number, which is actually 2.0.0 :/

Comment: any error message in any of the log files? `graph.db/messages.log` It has to be in. Can you show a listing of your server's lib directory where you extracted the jar's to? And you used the 2.0 branch of the neo4j-shell tools?

Comment: stupid me, expecting a 1.9.7 server, whereas I was running 2.0.0. There's a special version of import-tools for 2.0.0. This should solve itself now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, version 2.0 needs a special distribution of the import tools, located at: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/tree/20

Make sure to delete all previous version of import-tools, just overwriting won't do as some filenames are different from both packages.
restart server, start shell and you're good to go.

Comment: I also just updated that to 2.0.0 (it was at 2.0.0-RC1)

Comment: Yes, it seems to. I have the commands at my disposal. I'm trying to import GEOFF files, but "RuleFormatException: Syntax error in rule" is a tad vague, so I'm checking all my code to see where I'm making the error...